# Generalised Matrices (to solve system of linear equations) in R

Tags: r, matrix, system

I need to solve a system of linear equations in R - which I have been able to do just fine.  Please see code below:

```
A<-matrix(c(1:5,2,1,2:4,3,2,1:3,4:2,1,2,5:1),nrow=5) #Creates a matrix of the coefficients
A #Displays the matrix of coefficients (below)

     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,]    1    2    3    4    5
[2,]    2    1    2    3    4
[3,]    3    2    1    2    3
[4,]    4    3    2    1    2
[5,]    5    4    3    2    1

kv<-matrix(c(7,-1,-3,5,17),nrow=5) #Creates a column vector of the known values

kv #Displays the column vector

     [,1]
[1,]    7
[2,]   -1
[3,]   -3
[4,]    5
[5,]   17

solve(A,kv) #Solves the continuous equation

     [,1]
[1,]   -2
[2,]    3
[3,]    5
[4,]    2
[5,]   -4
```

The problem is I now need to generalise my solution to it can be used on systems of equations of the same structure but of a larger size - WITHOUT keying in all the values of matrix A as I have above.

Is anyone able to point me in the correct direction of how I can do the matrix of coefficients but in a way that the program can be used to solve other systems?

Any help would be gratefully received
Thanks

Comment: Ummm... what is the source of your matrix coefficients in the first place? For example, is someone sending you a bunch text strings like `k*y1 = a*x1 + b*x2 + c*x3`  and you want to extract the values "k,a,b,c" ?

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly:

```
bandmat <- function(n){
require(Matrix)
as.matrix(bandSparse(n,n,-(n-1):(n-1),diag=lapply(c(n:1,2:n),function(i) rep(i,n))))
}

bandmat(4)

     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    1    2    3    4
[2,]    2    1    2    3
[3,]    3    2    1    2
[4,]    4    3    2    1
```

There might be a more convenient way to construct this.

Edit:
Here is how you use it.

```
#create some vector
set.seed(42)
kv <- sample(-10:10,10)
#[1]  9  8 -5  4  0 -2  1 -9  5  2

#solve equation system
solve(bandmat(length(kv)),kv)
#[1]  0.0 -6.0 11.0 -6.5  1.0  2.5 -6.5 12.0 -8.5  2.0
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply.  That is kind of what I'm after but it needs to be generalised so rather than specify bandmat (4) I need it to fit any size of matrix - is that possible?

Comment: @TanyaKiddle I don't understand. You can calculate a matrix with this band structure of any size. Just try `bandmat(10)`.

Comment: That's great thanks;sorry I misunderstood. I now need to solve the continuous equations.I have code to display the column vector                                                                  kv<-matrix(c(7,-1,-3,5,17),nrow=5).                            When I manually created matrix (A) I used following code to solve equations                                                               >solve(A,kv)                                                              This now won't work-can you please suggest how I can do the equivalent of > solve(A,kv) incorporating your matrix function?  Thanks

Comment: @TanyaKiddle I still don't understand the problem, but added an example of using the function to my answer.